# Is adding a lot of loop cuts bad?

Tags: modeling, edges

Im creating a mesh, or more specifically a very detailed robot. I look for modeling suggestions to the following concerns.(see below)

1. is it suggested that i use a lot of edge loop (for definitions sake), while also using a subsurfice modifier.
2. for some reason i feel like all of my edge loop are going to bite me right back later on. (has this happened to you? if so what do you suggest)

p.s I'm box modeling.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the situation and what you're modeling.

Generally, I try to get the main shape of my model in before adding in the subserf, and then once it's to the point where I need extra geometry, or smoothing, I'll add in the subserf, and start to add in holding edges.

If an edge loop isn't adding anything, get rid of it. Every vertex should have a purpose.

If you're getting to the point where you think that it's becoming a bit too messy, it could be a good idea to retopologize your mesh to streamline the topology.

Comment: Yeah, i think I'm  loop are going to turn on me because there are tons of vertices that "Don't serve a purpose."

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably want to do some retopology then. Good luck! :)